# Client needs expression in article

Tags: project, writing

This is my first time working as a writer. I've sent my client a written article. He checked it and sent the following message:

> **Client:**
>   It is good, but I need the expression : "Hydroponic supplies" to appear 5 time at least!

What does he mean by "expression"? Is he talking about writing the specific words "hydroponic supplies" in the article? If not, what does he mean by it?

Comment: Why didn't you just ask the client what he meant?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about word usage, and not about freelancing. It appears to be on-topic for [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/), but please check their question guidelines first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "hydroponic supplies" is the *expression*.  He wants that string of text to appear at least 5 times in the article.

My guess is that this article is for web content and he wants search engines to find this article when people search for "hydroponic supplies."

So, as they used to say to us in English class when we learned new words  - use it in a sentence.  (In this case, at least five times.)

Answer (score 0):

[From the Merriam Webster dictionary defining "expression"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expression):

ex·pres·sion noun \ik-ˈspre-shən\
: the act of making your thoughts, feelings, etc., known by speech, writing, or some other method : the act of expressing something

: a word or phrase

: the way someone's face looks that shows emotions and feelings